# Un-Catchable IOException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

ASPX.NET application that uses XDocument.Load() to read from an XML file. At times it will throw an IOException static that the file cannot be opened b/c it is in use by another process. I cannot recreate this at will by opening the file and reloading the site. But what's even more odd is that the exception occurs from within a Try-Catch block where I am explicitly catching System.IOException.

Here is the stack:

> Exception type: IOException
>
> Thread information: 
>       Thread ID: 18 
>       Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
>       Is impersonating: False 
>       Stack trace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
>      at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
>      at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
>      at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
>      at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
>      at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
>      at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri)
>
> **at StatTick.Controls.ChartSlider.getXMLFile(String url) in removedpath\StatTick\Controls\ChartSlider.ascx.cs:line 27
>      at StatTick.Controls.ChartSlider.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in removedpath\StatTick\Controls\ChartSlider.ascx.cs:line 21**

Here is the code:

```
private XDocument getXMLFile(string url)
    {
        XDocument tempDoc;

        t("Looking For XML File");
        int tryCount = 0;
        //string URL = "~/tempCharts/imageList.xml";
        while (tryCount++ < 10)
        {

            try
            {
                tempDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(url));
                return tempDoc;
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                t("Error accessing XML File, sleeping for 10ms and then trying again\r\nTryCount: " + tryCount.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                continue;

            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Hopefully someone will be able to offer some insight into this matter for me.

Thanks

**EDIT**
Ok here is what I've Done, I'll have to do some testing to verify it no longer throws Thanks for the quick responses!:

```
while (tryCount <= 10)
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(url), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fStream);

                    foreach (XElement xe in xDoc.Descendants("ImageUrl"))
                    {
                        t("Added: " + xe.Value);
                        tempImageUrlList.Add(xe.Value);
                    }
                    t("Done with Image List!");
                }
                return tempImageUrlList;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                t("Error access XML File, sleeping for 10ms and then trying again\r\nTryCount: " + tryCount.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a stream instead and use it load the XML.You can be sure that the underlying stream is closed with a using statement.

```
using (Stream s = File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(url)))
{
        XDocument.Load(s);
}
```

Or

```
using (FileStream fs= new FileStream(Server.MapPath(url), FileMode.Open,
                                          FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
        XDocument.Load(fs);
}
```

;

Comment: I'm doing some testing on this and will mark as answer once I get some solid results. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think the error is becuse of the access permission for the file so please give read/write permission to the file and then try reading file.